# Инвентарь с быстрым доступом к предметам Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть инвентарь с предметами игрока, и так же я сделал слоты для быстрого доступа к предметам, я хочу когда игрок нажимает на клавиши от 1 - 8, выбирался необходимый слот инвентаря с быстрым доступом, как это можно сделать, с помощью IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler я сделал если пользователь вводит по инвентарю, то я делаю необходимое например вывожу подробную информацию о инвентарном слоте, но теперь мне нужна другая логика относящияся к быстрым слотам, на быстрые клавиши, есть что то похожее в Unity, или придеться колхозить вешать на каждый UI скрипт и проверять его порядковый номер и нажатую кнопку пользователем.

[image: Инвентарь с быстрым доступом]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Update засунуть:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        // здесь смена предмета
    }
```

Цифру в KeyCode.Alpha можно поменять на другую нужную. Или другую клавишу впринципе вместо Alpha
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Comment: Спасибо, пришлось делать таким образом как вы указали, но я сделал немного по другому, я навесил 1 скрипт на Panel который, проверяет нажат ли была клавиша если нажат то какая, с помощью таблицы ASCII сверяются необходимые мне клавиши, это клавиши от 1 - 8 и бегает по ребенкам ищет необходимого, и активирует его допустим, вместо того что бы кидать на каждый слот 1 и тот же скрипт, с измененной клавишой в коде.

Comment: Все таки мы программисты, и должны избавляться от повторяющегося кода, и уменьшать себе лишней работы